# Reset "Open with calibre" options

Tags: windows-10, file-association

I gave my laptop to my sister for some time now I have this thing popping up on every Document file I try to open.

[image: 'How do you want to open this file?' prompt]

Comment: Do you have Word installed? If so open Settings > Default Apps and set Word as the default handler for .docx file type.

Comment: yes I have MSOffice installed

Answer (score 0):

Repairing Office should fix the .doc/docx file associations.

Right-click the Start button, and select Apps and Features on the pop-up menu.
Select the Microsoft Office product you want to repair, and select Modify.
Select Repair.

**References:**

- [Repair an Office application - Office Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/repair-an-office-application-7821d4b6-7c1d-4205-aa0e-a6b40c5bb88b?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
- [Double-clicking an Office file fails to open it in the correct Office program - Office Support](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/double-clicking-an-office-file-fails-to-open-it-in-the-correct-office-program-1e9c0ad9-34c8-4440-a42e-d30186b29ed6)